# How do I wait for an object to NOT be clickable?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I can easily check whether an object is clickable: -

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="table-defaults-7"]/div/div/div/div/span/button[2]')))
```

Is there a way to do the opposite? My scenario is that I have a page with a Save and Cancel button. When I change data on the page both buttons become clickable, but when I click Save they both then become not clickable and this is the event I need to check for to ensure the save button has been clicked.

Is this possible?

Cheers

Comment: Check if isEnabled() method helps you here. This method returns a boolean value so just assert whether isEnabled() returns false for the element you are trying  to verify as not being clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming your `save` button has an attribute that can be either `enabled`
 or `disabled`.
Assuming the attribute that toggles between enabled and disabled is named `status`.

```
import time

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'your xpath')

#after clicking the save button

buttonStatus = element.get_property('status')    # should be "enabled"
timeout = 0

# loop till the status becomes disabled or a timeout
while buttonStatus != 'disabled' and timeout <= 5:
    buttonStatus = element.get_property('status')
    timeout += 1
    time.sleep(1)                               # sleep for 1 second
```

Do check with `element.is_enabled()` method and change the above code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. As it turned out I had a boolean attribute called 'disabled' that I used along with your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try negation (`not` method).

**java** version:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(not(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='table-defaults-7']/div/div/div/div/span/button[2]'"))));
```

link here:

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#not-org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition-